# Passwordless ssh to vagrant to load another user after vagrant ssh

Tags: ssh, openssh, vagrant

I have a new user in my vagrant box(trusty64) and I am trying to ssh into it. Instead of logging into `vagrant` user after `vagrant up`, I want to login to my username.

*What I have done so far*

1. Created a user in my guest machine.
2. Created ssh key in my host using `ssh-keygen`
3. Copied the ssh key to the guest using `ssh-copy-id -p 2222 -i shash@127.0.0.1`

*and the part of the Vagrantfile looks like this*

```
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.ssh.username = "shash"
  config.ssh.forward_agent = true
  config.ssh.private_key_path = "~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

I can use `ssh -p '2222' 'shash@127.0.0.1'` to login directly but when I give `vagrant up` I keep getting the following error

```
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

Any help in sorting out this is really appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`config.ssh.private_key_path` should point to your private key file (usually `~/.ssh/id_rsa` — the name of the file is displayed when you run `ssh-keygen`), *not* `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Comment: May you complete your answer by adding the instruction about how to find and change it?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to accomplish this is adding the following to the bottom of `~vagrant/.bashrc`:

```
ssh chsc
exit
```

If you want avoid the trouble of creating and installing an SSH key, you can use `su` instead; however this does not allow `ssh` inside the Vagrant box to use your SSH forward agent if you need to connect to external servers from within the box:

```
sudo su chsc
exit
```

When making such changes to `~vagrant/.bashrc` you risk locking yourself out of the shell if you make an error. I recommend keeping an open terminal logged in as `vagrant`, until you have ensured that everything works. If something goes wrong, just rename .bashrc (`mv .bashrc .bashrc-bak`).